# How many arrangements for 7 seven numbers so that every four consecutive have sum divisible by 3?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integers

In how many ways can one arrange the numbers 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, and 160
such that the sum of every four consecutive numbers is divisible by 3?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  If  $3\,|\,(a+b+c)$ and $3\,|\,(b+c+d)$ can you show that $3\,|\,(d-a)$?

Comment: i did not understand what you mean can you expand more or show me what you mean?

Comment: I should have had sums with four terms.  That is, suppose $a,b,c,d,e$ are integers such that $3$ divides $a+b+c+d+e$ and $3$ divides $b+c+d+e$, then show that $3$ divides $e-a$.  This is applicable to your problem, where we have $a,b,c,d,e$ as the first five integers in your arrangement.

Comment: Actually, the problem would be more interesting if it required that the sum of every three consecutive terms was divisible by $3$.  As it is...well, start by looking for examples.  Can you write one down?

Comment: okey i'll write it down wait a minute

Comment: the problem is that 3 divides the sum of 100+110+120+130+140 but it doesn't divide 110+120+130+140

Comment: Well, you have to consider other orders for those numbers.

Comment: it doesn't work in other cases... because we need consecutive numbers so we cannot change the order of the numbers.. for example if we put 110+120+130+140+150  the sum is not divisible by 3 and also if we start from 120 to 160 the sum is not divisible by 3

Comment: You are not understanding the question. It asks about "arrangements" of these numbers.  That is, you put them in order, but then you have to test the desired property.

Comment: Oh yes i am really sorry okay i will try to prove what you have asked me to do and come back

Comment: I chose the order: 150+100+110+140+160 that its sum is divisible by 3 and also: 100+110+140+160 is divisible by 3 but the problem is that even when I change the "e" number I cannot change the "a" because in that case I won't have the sum divisible by 3. and whenever I have in all cases e-a is never divisible by 3. And I have a question, I need to know the number of arrangements possible, won't i need to use permuations rule?

Comment: I don't believe there are any arrangements that work with the stated condition.  That's why I said that the problem is more interesting if the rule is for $\textit {three}$ consecutive numbers instead of four.  Are you sure you write the problem correctly?

Comment: I just posted an argument to show that there are no arrangements that work with the given rule. Again, if the rule was for any three consecutive numbers then there are some arrangements.

Comment: thank you, yes the problem that I have is talking about four consecutive numbers and that's what created the problem for me too because I tried many rules and none worked because exactly any consecutive numbers that I choose are not divisible by 3 and the residue is 1

Comment: i have a question why did you use at the beginning five numbers that are a+b+c+d+e and then just b+c+d+e and then saw if e-a is divisible by 3? is this an existing rul

Comment: If $3\,|\,(a+b+c+d)$ then $(a+b+c+d)=3n$ for some integer $n$.  Similarly, if $3\,|\,(b+c+d+e)$ then $(b+c+d+e)=3m$.  Subtracting we see that $3(m-n)=e-a$ so $e-a$ is divisible by $3$.  That's what I wanted to establish.

Comment: aaaah okeeey thank youuu so muuuch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the rule as stated there are no arrangements that work.

Proof:  For any five integers, $a,b,c,d,e$, such that $3\,|\,(a+b+c+d)$ and $3\,|\,(b+c+d+e)$ we must have $3\,|\,(e-a)$.  Thus, if your supposed arrangement is $n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_7$  we must have $$n_1\equiv n_5\quad n_2\equiv n_6\quad n_3\equiv n_7\pmod 3$$

Now, $\pmod 3$ your list is $$\{1,2,0,1,2,0,1\}$$

So we note that there are three $1's$ and two each of $0's$ and $2's$.

The block $n_1,n_2,n_3$ repeats as $n_5,n_6,n_7$ $\pmod 3$ with $n_4$ being the odd man odd.  Since $1$ is only residue that appears an odd number of numbers, we must have $n_4\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  But then $n_1,n_2,n_3$ are $0,1,2$ in some order which makes $$n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4\equiv 0+1+2+1\equiv 1 \not \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$ and we are done.